# Bounds on the following mixture model?

Tags: probability, distributions, probability-inequalities

I have two random variables $y,z$:

1. $y$ is the product of a normal distribution and an independent lognormal distribution $\rightarrow$ so a lognormal mixture, &
2. $z \propto {\rm{log}} \ |y|$

In view of the above, how can I simplify the following expression:
$$ \mathbb{E} [\Delta(z,y).y] $$
where $\Delta(z,y) = \frac{z-y}{y}$? And $|\Delta(z,y)| \leq \alpha$ where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

I would like to ideally get, for some constant $C(y)$ defined in terms of the covariance of $y$: $ \mathbb{E} [\Delta(z,y).y] \leq C(y) .\mathbb{E} [\Delta(z,y)]  \mathbb{E} [y] $

$\underline{Thought}$:
Is there a possibility to get the above upper-bound using results from the sub-gaussianity literature, e.g., http://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.3027v7.pdf?

Answer (score 1):

$\Delta(z,y).y = \frac{z-y}{y}.y = z-y = K\log\vert y\vert - y$, for some $K$, then $\mathbb{E} [\Delta(z,y).y] = \mathbb{E} [K\log\vert y\vert - y]$.

If $K>0$, then you can use the upper bound $\log\vert y \vert \leq \vert y\vert -1$ to obtain the bound $\mathbb{E} [K\log\vert y\vert - y] \leq \mathbb{E} [K\vert y\vert -K - y]$, and expand it if you wish to do so.